# Subdomain created but not running properly

Tags: server, subdomain, cpanel, subdirectory

I'm not sure if this question belongs here but because it is a technical question so I'm asking it here. Feel free to move it to any appropriate website of Stack exchange.

My problem is I have created a subdomain successfully on my website through cpanel and also put an index.html file in it to test it. But when I run it in browser it is not showing contents of index.html file. It shows following errors:

**DNS address could not be found** and **ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED** errors. Can someone please tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'd guess misspelling or a lag between updating cpanel and it updating the zone file.

Comment: @Rudiger: There is no spelling mistake but can you please tell me what is zone file? Do I need to update it as well and where is it located? It will be really helpful of you.

Comment: A zone file is what holds your DNS records, i.e. what domain name points to what IP. When you update it in CPanel it updates the zone files. Sometimes there are caches or delays with it.

Answer (score 2):

You must be missing **A record** pointing to your *sub domain* in your **domain panel**.

```
Record     Point to       TTL

A           sub           300
```

Comment: Thanks. Even though I was missing A record to my subdomain but it was only partially true. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the DNS servers for your domain. You might be using external DNS servers. When you create a subdomain on cPanel, a DNS entry is created in the DNS zone for that subdomain pointing to your server ip. If your domain uses external DNS servers then those servers will be queried to find the ip address for that subdomain. In this case you should manually edit your DNS zone and add an A record for that subdomain to point to your server's ip).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. Here is how solved my problem. The problem was that I have purchased a hosting with one domain name. I also have another domain purchase but there is no hostng on it. I had pointed the second domain to first domain which also has hosting support. So what I was doing is I was creating subdomain on second one on the first domain. But it was not recognising it and showing DNS problem. So I made an entry A record entry in the second domain about the subdomain which I wanted to create on it. And then in 5 minutes DNS was updated and issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the subdomain, go to the DNS editor of the domain and add a CNAME record for the subdomain.

For example:

```
NAME                          TYPE     VALUE
--------------------------------------------------
subdomain.example.com.        CNAME    example.com.
```